# Ktor on App Engine with Java 17 runtime unable to read request headers

Tags: google-app-engine, retrofit, ktor, java-17

I just migrated from Java 8 runtime to Java 17 on my Ktor project that runs on Google App Engine Standard environment.

The project compiles and is being deployed without issues, the request response is sent by the server, Even querying a database(MongoDB atlas in this case) also works.

The issue I see is when there is a header attached to the request, the Ktor route fails  to read them and throws a with Http 500 error.

Here is my client(Android - Retrofit ) code:

```
    val request = chain.request()
    val authTokenRequest = request.newBuilder()
        .addHeader(FIRE_AUTH_UID_KEY, mFirebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid?:"fakeUid")
        .addHeader(FIRE_AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, returnUserFireAuthIdToken())
        .addHeader(FIRE_APP_CHECK_TOKEN_KEY, returnUserFireBaseAppCheck())
        .build()

object RetrofitInterceptorObject {

    val retrofitInterceptorObject by lazy {
        RetrofitInterceptor()
    }

}

private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(RetrofitInterceptorObject.retrofitInterceptorObject)
    .build()
```

Here is the get request

```
@GET("/getInviteCodeToShare")
suspend fun getInviteCodeToShare(): Response<InviteCodeToShare>
```

Ktor route:

```
fun Route.getInviteCodeToShare() {

route("/getInviteCodeToShare") {
    get {
        val uid = call.request.header(FIRE_AUTH_UID_KEY)!! //this is what is causing the error
        val authToken = call.request.header(FIRE_AUTH_TOKEN_KEY)!!
        val userAuthDetails = UserAuthDetails(uid, authToken)

        if ( isUserValid(userAuthDetails) ) {
            //Successful
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.OK, getTheInviteCodeToShare(uid))
            } else {
                //else return you are not logged in to client
                call.respond(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, unAuthorizedRequest)
                println("User is not authorized")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code was working without issues in Java 8 runtime.